# Average number of seconds between two time observations

Tags: r, xts, difftime

I have a irregular time index from an xts object. I need to find the ***average number of seconds between two time observations.*** This is the my sample data:

```
dput(tt)
structure(c(1371.25, NA, 1373.95, NA, NA, 1373, NA, 1373.95, 
1373.9, NA, NA, 1374, 1374.15, NA, 1374, 1373.85, 1372.55, 1374.05, 
1374.15, 1374.75, NA, NA, 1375.9, 1374.05, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 1375, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1376.35, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1376.25, NA, 1378, 1376.5, NA, NA, NA, 1378, 
1378, NA, NA, 1378.8, 231.9, 231.85, NA, 231.9, 231.85, 231.9, 
231.8, 231.9, 232.6, 231.95, 232.35, 232, 232.1, 232.05, 232.05, 
232.05, 231.5, 231.3, NA, NA, 231.1, 231.1, 231.1, 231, 231, 
230.95, 230.6, 230.6, 230.7, 230.6, 231, NA, 231, 231, 231.45, 
231.65, 231.4, 231.7, 231.3, 231.25, 231.25, 231.4, 231.4, 231.85, 
231.75, 231.5, 231.55, 231.35, NA, 231.5, 231.5, NA, 231.5, 231.25, 
231.15, 231, 231, 231, 231.05, NA), .Dim = c(60L, 2L), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "Asia/Calcutta", tzone = "Asia/Calcutta", index = structure(c(1459482299, 
1459482301, 1459482302, 1459482303, 1459482304, 1459482305, 1459482306, 
1459482307, 1459482309, 1459482310, 1459482311, 1459482312, 1459482314, 
1459482315, 1459482316, 1459482317, 1459482318, 1459482319, 1459482320, 
1459482321, 1459482322, 1459482323, 1459482324, 1459482326, 1459482328, 
1459482329, 1459482330, 1459482331, 1459482332, 1459482336, 1459482337, 
1459482338, 1459482339, 1459482342, 1459482344, 1459482346, 1459482347, 
1459482348, 1459482349, 1459482590, 1459482591, 1459482594, 1459482595, 
1459482596, 1459482597, 1459482598, 1459482599, 1459482602, 1459482603, 
1459482604, 1459482609, 1459482610, 1459482611, 1459482612, 1459482613, 
1459482618, 1459482619, 1459482620, 1459482622, 1459482628), tzone = "Asia/Calcutta", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("A", "B")), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"))
```

This is my attempt:

```
difftime(index(tt),index(lag.xts(tt, k=1)), units=c("auto"))
Time differences in secs
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
attr(,"tclass")
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

> Edit:

Based on the answers, I have made the following code. ***The code is meant to calculate mean number of seconds for A and B every day.***

But the code takes the index of tt instead of A or B and so the results of A and B is same.

```
fun.time= function(x) mean(diff(time(x)))
df.time<-do.call(rbind, lapply(split(tt, "days"), FUN=function (x) {do.call(cbind, lapply(as.list(x), fun.time))})) 


dput(df.time)
structure(c(5.57627118644068, 5.57627118644068), .Dim = 1:2, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("A", "B")))
```

Comment: try this `attributes(tt)$index %>% diff %>% mean`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First create some test data that has more than one day, tt2.  We use tt to form it where tt is from the question.  Define two functions:

- mean_diff_time which removes NA's from its argument and then converts it to numeric taking the mean diff of that.
- dates which converts its argument to Date class

Finally using aggregate.zoo we aggregate it by date applying mean_diff_time to each date group.

```
library(xts)

# create test input tt2 having >1 day (tt is from question)
tt2 <- tt
time(tt2) <- time(tt) + seq(1, 24*60*60, length = 60)

mean_diff_time <- function(x) mean(diff(as.numeric(time(na.omit(x)))))
dates <- function(x) as.Date(format(x))

aggregate(tt2, dates, mean_diff_time, coredata = FALSE)
##                       A        B
##     2016-04-01 3029.006 1648.939
##     2016-04-02 5416.096 1632.957
```

### Update

Have revised answer in light of new features.

Comment: can I sum it first and then check the mean?

Comment: @runjumpify.  Please clarify.

Comment: I have checked. and the code is fine. Please see the edit.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the last table you show is what I need. I guess I missed the na.omit in my mean function. But why my code shows a different result than yours?

Comment: As I have used the same tt2 for my code and yours, it should give the same result.

Comment: The problem is that the date of a time depends on which time zone the date is taken with respect to.   Unfortunately R is inconsistent when it comes to such decisions.  For example, compare these two: `as.Date(time(tt2)[50]); time(tt2)[50]` .   Neither is right or wrong but just assume different time zones.  I have modified the `aggregate` statement in (3) to use `format(times)` and now it gives the same as your answer.  If you use chron (which has no time zones) in place of POSIXct you can't have these problems.

Comment: This is strange. And one must be cautious.

Comment: What format(times) does in this case to resolve the issue?

Comment: @runjumpify, format(x) where x is POSIXct gives a character string with no time zone so the result of applying any function to it cannot depend on the time zone.  Look at `format(time(tt2))` and at `time(tt2)`.  Of course even this may not be the solution you want if format() does not convert to character with respect to the time zone you wanted; however, I have found that usually it does work in the way you want.  The R Help Desk article in R News 4/1 discusses this some more. https://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf

Comment: Thanks @G. Grothendieck

Comment: Lastly, I would like to know whether my code is also correct?

Comment: It's correct if it's working with respect to the time zone you intend.  Did you want to split the data with respect to the local time zone?  GMT?  the tzone attribute of `tt2`?

Comment: local time zone IST

Comment: Then it's correct. You can check that it split it in the way you wanted by printing tt2 and also printing `split(tt2, "days")`.

Comment: I am very much puzzled. split(tt2, "days") shows warning:  timezone of object (Asia/Calcutta) is different than current timezone (). But when I do Sys.timezone() I get [1] "Asia/Calcutta". Both are same then why there is a warning?

Comment: I think its a problem with xts.  If you convert the object to zoo you won't get that.  `as.zoo(ttc2)`.

Answer (score 2):

To supplement the answer by G.Grothendieck, you can also use `mean(diff(index(tt)))`to return the result as a `difftime` object:

```
> mean(diff(index(tt)))
Time difference of 5.576271 secs
```

or simply `mean(diff(.index(tt)))` to get the result as numeric:

```
> mean(diff(.index(tt)))
[1] 5.576271
```

EDIT:

```
> lapply(tt, function(x){mean(diff(.index(x[!is.na(x)])))})
$A
[1] 14.95455

$B
[1] 6.211538
```

Comment: Thank you. Please see the edited part of the question.